# PHP mySqli not updating table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to update the table but nothing is changing. The database name and fields are correct.

```
<?php
require("config.php");
    $forname  = $_POST['name'];
    $newval = "yes";
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE pupils SET signin = '$newval' WHERE forname = '$forname'");
    mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Help appreciated! 
Thanks,

UPDATE

Appears that data is not posting correctly for some reason.

```
<form class="form-inline" name="markin" role="form" method="POST" action="markin.php">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name"name" id="name">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `pupils` WHERE signin = 'no'";//Grab the data
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {//Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<option>" . $row['forname'] . "</option>";//$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Mark in</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: [ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: That's not very helpful...

Comment: Ensure that data is actually posted and that the value for `$_POST['forname']` is actually in `pupils`.

Comment: @AlexisKing serious? You forgot at the start one [`h`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and and at the end one [`h`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: @crablab Do you get any errors? Did you checked that the connection didn't failed? (Error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`)

Comment: You're not checking for any MySQL(i) errors at all. Do that.

Comment: Correction: appears that data isn't posting correctly-sorry. Name is same at both ends and form is configured correclty.Not sure what is happening... @Ding

Comment: You have a typo. See my updated answer

Comment: Real simple `name"name"` <= add `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you read the [prepared statements quickstart guide](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) which would lead you to something like this...

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE pupils SET signin = ? WHERE forname = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $newval, $forname);
$stmt->execute();
```

As an added bonus, you should set *mysqli* to throw exceptions on error so you don't have to check return values all the time. In your `config.php` file, before creating the connection, do this...

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = new mysqli(...); // or however you create $con
```

and as mentioned in the comments, the `php.ini` file in your development environment should enable full error reporting with the following directives

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

---

To directly answer your question, you're missing an equals sign for the `<select>` elements `name` attribute. It should be

```
<select class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
```

Comment: Is it not possible to continue using it this way? All my other queries are formatted thus and I would prefer not go around fixing them.

Comment: Of course it's possible but it's hardly a wise decision

Comment: I see. I did some debugging and it appears the form isn't posting...even though it was a few minutes ago. Running the query with a harcoded variable for forname edited the table as expected,

Comment: Having full error reporting would have alerted you to the fact that `$_POST['forname']` didn't exist

Comment: Yeah, I take the point and on future projects I will read up on this.